# Finding number of k-prime numbers;

Tags: c, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Given a range `a` to `b` , and number `k`, find all the k-prime numbers between `a` to `b` [inclusive both]. 
Definition of k-prime : A number is a k-prime if it has exactly k distinct prime factors.

i.e. `a=4`, `b=10` `k=2` the answer is `2`. Since the prime factors of 6 are [2,3] and the prime factors of 10 are [2,5].

Now here's my attempt

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int numOfInp;
    scanf("%d",&numOfInp);
    int a,b,k;  
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&k);
    int *arr;
    arr = (int*)calloc(b+1,sizeof(int));

    int i=2,j=2,count=0; 
    //Count is the count of distic k prim factors for a particular number
    while(i<=b){
        if(arr[i]==0){
            for(j=i;j<=b;j=j+i){
                arr[j]++;
            }
        }
        if(i>=a && arr[i]==k)
            count++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

**This problem is taken from [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/JULY13/problems/KPRIME)**

Here's what I've done, I take an array of size b, and for each number starting from 2, I do the following.

For 2 check if `arr[2]` is 0, then `arr[2]++,arr[4]++,arr[6]++ ....` so on.

For 3 check if `arr[2]` is 0, then `arr[3]++,arr[6]++,arr[9]++ ....` so on.

Since `arr[4]` is not zero, leave it.

In the end, the value `arr[i]` will give me the answer, i.e `arr[2]` is 1, hence 2 is 1-prime number, `arr[6]` is 2, hence 6 is 2-prime number.

Questions:

1. What is the complexity of this code, and can it be done in O(n)?
2. Am I using Dynamic Programming here?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Do you know how to calculate complexity?

Comment: @levengli No, it's not homework, I guess the complexity would be n/2 + n/3 + n/4 + n/5 ... and so on..

Comment: @Kraken There is a loop inside a loop with inner loop's variables depending on the outer loop. A sign of `O(n^2)` complexity. Also your indentation can be better, it is hard to read the code.

Comment: @AseemBansal Yeah, but the inner loop is not really executed n times now, is it?
It will be n/2 the first time, n/3 the second time, n/4 the next[actually n/4 is skipped ], .. and so on..

Comment: How many such `n` terms will be there? That will be proportional to `n` itself. So their sum will be proportional to `n * n`. So `O(n^2)` complexity. Try it by hand for various numbers. Take out the denominator terms as they aren't considered anyways.

Comment: @AseemBansal Anyway to get it down to O(n)?

Comment: @AseemBansal Actually, you know exactly how many times you will run the inner loop. You will run it once for each prime in the range `[2,b]`. This number of primes is not `b` it is smaller. The algorithm is know as sieve of eratosthenes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_complexity

Comment: @cyon My mistake I thought it was `j=j+1` instead of `j=j+i`.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this has the complexity of `n*log(n)`

Comment: It is dynamic programming, having used the `calloc()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you are using is know as [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It is a well known algorithm for finding prime numbers. Now to answer your questions :

1a) What is the complexity of this code

The complexity of your code is `O(n log(log n))`.

For and input of `a` and `b` the complexity of your code is `O(b log log b)`. The runtime is due to the fact that you first mark `b/2` number then `b/3` then `b/5` and so on. So your runtime is `b * (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/11 + ... + 1/prime_closest_to_b)`. What we have there is a [prime harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_harmonic_series) which grows asymptotically as `ln(ln(b+1))` (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant)).

Asymptotically the upper bound is:

```
O(b * (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 +..)) = O(b) * O(log(log(b+1))) = O(b*log(log(b))
```

1b) Can it be done in `O(n)`

This is tricky. I would say that for all practical purposes an `O(n log log n)` algorithm is gonna be about as good as any `O(n)` algorithm, since `log(log(n))` grows really really really slow.

Now, if my life depended on it I would try to see if I can find a method to generate all numbers up to `n` in a way where every operation generates a unique number and tells me how many unique prime divisors it has.

2) Am I using Dynamic Programming here?

Definition of dynamic programming from wikipedia says:

> Dynamic programming is a method for solving complex problems by breaking them down into simpler subproblems

The definition is quite broad, so it is unfortunately open to interpretation. I would say that this isn't dynamic programming, because you aren't breaking down your problem into smaller **smaller** sub-problems and using the results from those sub-problems to find the final answer.